# Were the events in "Passion" really happening or a dream?

Tags: plot-explanation, passion

I have just seen the film [Passion (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1829012/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), and seriously, I don't get any of it. Wikipedia does not have a detailed storyline of the movie and other sites just have a review. I would like to know what the story really is — Is it a dream or really happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem pretty confusing from the plot descriptions on Wikipedia and IMDB, and even the trailer seems confusing. But, Wikipedia says the movie is really a remake of a French movie named [Love Crime](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1459012/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). The [plot description of Love Crime on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Crime) seems a lot more detailed and reads as follows:

> Set in and around Paris, France, the story revolves around two women who work in a multinational corporation. Christine (Scott Thomas) is a cold, ruthless business executive who enjoys using and betraying people. Isabelle (Sagnier) is Christine's young, ambitious and intelligent administrative assistant who regularly suffers from professional and personal humiliations at the hands of Christine.
>
> A subplot revolves around Christine's boyfriend, Philippe, who is cheating on her with Isabelle. When Christine discovers accounting irregularties in Philippe's business accounts with the firm, Christine threatens him instead of reporting him, hoping to use him to her own advantage.
>
> Midway through the movie, Isabelle, after suffering one-too-many implied threats and humiliations by Christine, murders her by staging a break-in at Christine's suburban house and stabs her to death. Isabelle then implicates herself in the crime, a seeming sign of a nervous breakdown, when she allows herself to get arrested and incarcerated. At this point, the imprisoned Isabelle embarks on a quest to prove her innocence of a murder that she actually committed, but her defense may prove to be even more difficult than she anticipated due to her history with Christine and of the circumstantual evidence that Isabelle herself planted.

So based on what I've seen and read so far, the movie is *not* a dream.

Comment: This doesn't really relate to the specific plot of *Passion* at all, in particular the quite ambiguous ending that presents the most confusion. It only gives a rough rundown of the story of the original, but fails to mention the character of *Dani* (or any possible pendant of hers in the original), let alone what is and what is not truth at the ending, which is completely left out of the summary. Sure, the *whole* movie is not a dream, so much is pretty clear, but which *parts* of the movie are real or possibly a dream is absolutely not adressed here.

Answer (score 6):

- Isabelle was at her last wits and her life was crumbling down in
  front of her eyes as she killed Dani and since Dani sent the videos
  she knew her life was over.
- So in order to find justification in her actions and "relieve" her of
  her guilt, she DREAMS of Clarissa (twin sister killing herself) kind
  of like a full circle in the plot.
- If that really did happen the way Isabelle dreamt it then she
  would've been fulfilled in her guiltiness and finally freed from her 
  pain.
- BUT as the twist ending shot shown, Isabelle awakens and finds
  herself in the SAME situation that she left ----A murderer, a double 
  murderer now in deeper sh!$ because the videos the implicate her are 
  sent and she has no more tricks or ideas left in her bag.
- and having to deal with that "REALITY" (real life) is going to be
  even more pain and agony then she could've ever dream of.
- now that is the real twist/theme to the ending.